# Pass parameters to php in app.yaml Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, parameters, app.yaml

My problem is mentioned in the title but i will reiterate. I'm new to GAE and all of its stuff.My application uses PHP and Mysql. I have the mysql working in Cloud Sql and i've just deployed my app to app engine.

What does work: PHP scripts that require no parameters i.e. (FooBar.php)

What doesn't work: PHP scripts that I need to pass parameters i.e. (FooBar.php?foo=bar)

I believe the solution is how to configure the app.yaml file.

Again I'll say REGULAR PHP SCRIPTS EXECUTE.

THE ONES WHERE I REQUIRE PARAMETERS ARE MY ONLY PROBLEM.

Here's a sample of my app.yaml file

```
application: foo-bar-111
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1
```

Any help would be appreciated please!!!

Comment: I took a stab at fixing the formatting in your question, so the app.yaml is more legible. Is this *exactly* what your app.yaml file looks like? Besides adding leading spaces to have so format it as code, I also removed a quote at the beginning of the "application" line and another one at the end of the "- url" line -- just making sure that was a copy/paste error and that those characters aren't actually in your app.yaml file.

Comment: And, to be clear, what error are you receiving when visiting "/FooBar.php?foo=bar"? Is the "FooBar" handler getting called (just like when "/FooBar.php" is visited), or are you getting a 404 error, or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app.yaml you copied into your question (assuming the quotes I noted in the comments aren't really in your app.yaml file) looks fine for URLs both with and without parameters. It's unclear what error you are receiving and/or what unexpected behavior you're seeing.

To be clear, the app.yaml file routes the incoming request to your php script. The app.yaml file in your question should run the FooBar.php script for URL hits to both

```
/FooBar.php
```

and

```
/FooBar.php?foo=bar
```

The PHP script itself should access the parameter, if it exists, with

```
$_GET["foo"]
```

Is this what you're expecting, or are you wanting to route to a different script depending on different query string parameters? If the latter, I don't think that is possible -- you'll have to handle it in the script itself.

Also, is the URL you're referencing only using a query string? Definitely keep in mind that

```
/FooBar.php/foo-bar
```

or something along those lines, will not be matched by that yaml entry. If there is a possibility of having trailing characters in the path, remove the trailing "$" and instead include a ".*", such as:

```
- url: /(.+\.php).*
```

This would match all of the examples, and would send them all to your FooBar.php script.

[edited previous -- thanks to Stuart for catching the error in my previous answer]

Comment: Thanks mike. Could you show an example of how a url and script fields would look for that type of file with parameters? here is an example of the actual format for the app.yam file. http://image.slidesharecdn.com/appengine-php-140415030016-phpapp01/95/google-app-engine-for-php-developers-7-638.jpg?cb=1397548853

Comment: the query string is not used in matching the route - so this answer is unfortunately incorrect. you need to paste you app.yaml correctly into the question, for example I see a " in what you posted above.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. I already had regular php scripts executing and the format of my example got butchered by stack overflow haha. The link i provided is what my file looks like but how to format it to accept parameters is what i need a clear example of.

Comment: i can't see any link - just past in your app.yaml correctly so we can take a look.

Comment: Mike It's working!!!! I didn't know that it was able to hit the url with or without parameters. But i think the solution was the url and adding the ".*" and some debugging on my end. But your solution was the correct one. Thanks again buddy!!